# How to chain 2 EventListeners in Firebase-Android so that the first one doesn't continue until second one finishes?

Tags: java, android, firebase, async-await

I am trying to get some data from Firebase from listener A, then I will search under a different node with listener B based on some ID obtained from listener A, and when I receive the data from listener B, I want to append it to listener A data.
Basically I have 2 nodes in Firebase: posts & users. A post has some data, and a userID. When I want to display all posts in the database, I add each one to a RecyclerView, but before I add them to that View, I need to get some user data and only then (combinding these 2 gathered data) add it to the recyclerView.

I could not find anything onlineto try (other than some UI blocking things which I rather stay away as I am new to Android). I know Firebase is async and that Java does not have Promises or async/ await, so IDK what else to try. With my current implementation, I don't achieve what I want (obviously).

```
private void initialPopulatePostsFromDB(){
        mDatabase.limitToFirst(2).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<IndividualPost> postsDB = new ArrayList<>();

                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

 oldestPostId = postSnapShot.getKey();
                    final IndividualPost indivPost = postSnapShot.getValue(IndividualPost.class);
                    indivPost.setContents(typePostContents);

                    /*
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users").child(indivPost.getUserId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userAccount = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserAccount.class);

                            indivPost.setUserId(userAccount.getName());
                            System.out.println("[1] ACC NAME: " + indivPost.getUserId());
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    */

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users").child(indivPost.getUserId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userAccount = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserAccount.class);

                            indivPost.setUserId(userAccount.getName());
                            System.out.println("[1] ACC NAME: " + indivPost.getUserId());
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    System.out.println("[2] ACC NAME: " + indivPost.getUserId());
                    postsDB.add(indivPost);
                    System.out.println("[3] ACC NAME: " + indivPost.getUserId());
                }

                posts.addAll(postsDB);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I expect to display new data, data from user combined with the post.

```
I expected to be printed:
[1] ACC NAME John
[2] ACC NAME John
[3] ACC NAME John
but it's actually 
[2] BniepYpQuh6VgMF6L2
[3] BniepYpQuh6VgMF6L2
[1] John
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect to display new data, data from user combined with the post.

Reason you are not getting new data is because you are adding  `indivPost` to list and notifying recycle view in your first listener before getting user data in second listener.This way you can't achieve what you want because your `for loop` is synchronous and listener is asynchronous. Change your firebase structure to store user's name with posts, So you don't have to make a second call to get usernames.

Comment: I was aware of this, but the fix seems rather like a work around. Problem is even if I do this, I would like to learn how to really make it work.
Isn't there a way to block the first listener until the second one finishes? That's what I want to know & do if I would be given the right instructions.

Comment: @MariusMircea its not a work around. lets say you have 100k posts, will you call inner listener 100k times and block the user whole time? I don't think this is a better approach.

Comment: I guess you are right, I jus thought that adding data to the posts structure is not good practice (in the sense that if I need another thing at a later time, what would I do? add that data to posts make it a huge JSON?) Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to fix it this way.